# Tamanho de imagem no SVG

Tags: html, css

Estou tendo dificuldades para diminuir o tamanho da estrela no meu sistema, já tentei tirar o width e height do elemento svg, já tentei também colocar o 'viewbox', e até agora não obtive nenhum resultado, estou sem ideias k

```
<?php  if($nota == 5) {?> 
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg viewbox="2 2 0 40">
    <polygon points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198"  fill="black" style="fill:yellow"/>
</svg>
<?php } 
?>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4):

Na verdade tem uma aspas faltando na sua tag SVG, mas não é só esse o problema, as medidas do seu `viewbox` está bem estranha considerando os valores dos pontos do polígono. Além do mais, se o terceiro ou o quarto valor do `viewbox` for `0` o canvas do svg não vai ter "espaço" para renderizar o elemento

Eu ajustei o fechamento das aspas e coloquei o `viewbox` do tamanho dos maiores lados `198` e resolveu. Vc pode usar a largura:altura do tamanho que quiser, desde que mantenha a proporção `1:1` para não ficar com "espaço vazio" dentro do canvas do svg. Então tente manter tipo 100px de altura e largura, ou 120px etc...

```css
svg {
    width: 198px;
    height: 198px;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="2 2 198 198">
    <polygon points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198"  fill="black" style="fill:yellow"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro você precisa definir as dimensões da área do SVG que você deseja. Como a figura é representada por um quadrado, suponhamos que você deseja uma estrela com `100x100` pixels. Então defina o `width` e o `height` em `100px`:

**CSS:**

```
svg{
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
}
```

Agora você precisa definir as coordenadas dentro dessa área (para a estrela, são 5 coordenadas), separadas por vírgula sendo *x,y* (*x* é o eixo horizontal e *y* o eixo vertical) nos vértices indicados abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como SVG tem `100x100` pixels de dimensão, os valores da figura acima são as porcentagens aproximadas para se construir uma estrela perfeita, ou seja:

```
1º vértice: x = 50%, y = 0%
2º vértice: x = 19,49%, y = 100%
3º vértice: x = 100%, y = 37,93%
4º vértice: x = 0%, y = 37,93%
5º vértice: x = 80,51%, y = 100%
```

**Exemplo:**

```css
svg{
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="50,0 19.49,100 100,37.93 0,37.93 80.51,100"  fill="black" style="fill:yellow"/>
</svg>
```

> Dependendo do tamanho da estrela que você quer, basta aplicar as
>   porcentagens proporcionalmente nas coordenadas de acordo com as dimensões do quadrado.